# How to skip to next case instead of ending change calculation program?

Tags: c++, if-statement, switch-statement, case

I am constructing a recursion example for calculating change. Although I am compilling correctly, after calculation of how many pound coins (100 pences), the program ends instead of skipping to 50's coins. There seems to be missing something from the if statement that says how many coins used for the first step.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "change.h"
using namespace std;

//
main()
{
   int coin_value;
   coin_value = 100; 
   int change_needed;
   cout << "Please enter change needed in pence : ";
   cin >> change_needed;
   calculate_change(change_needed,coin_value);
}

void calculate_change ( int change_needed, int coin_value)
{
   int coins_used = 0;
   int remainder;
   int next_coin_value;
   while ( change_needed >= coin_value ) {
      change_needed -= coin_value;
      coins_used++;
      remainder = change_needed;
   }
   if ( coins_used > 0 )
      cout << "Coin value " << coin_value << " number of coins "<< coins_used << "\n";
   else {

      if (remainder == 0)
         return;
      else {
         next_coin_value = next_coin(coin_value);
         calculate_change(remainder,next_coin_value);
      }
   }
}

int next_coin (int coin_value)
{
   int next_coin_value;

   switch ( coin_value ) {
      case 100 : next_coin_value = 50;
                 break;
      case 50 : next_coin_value = 20;
                break;
      case 20 : next_coin_value = 10;
                break;
      case 10 : next_coin_value = 5;
                break;
      case 5 : next_coin_value = 2;
               break;
      case 2 : next_coin_value = 1;
               break;
      case 1 : next_coin_value = 0;
               break;
      default : cout << "unknown coin value" << coin_value << "\n";

   }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: I don't see a `return next_coin_value;` in `next_coin()`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp should I put a return in each case or just for the hole block?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp same thing, both ways.

Comment: That was just one of your issues. Look at `if (coins_used > 0) {..} else {...}`. What happens when this is true, but `remainder` is not 0?

Comment: That is the real problem, I have to add another else the leads to next_coin_value.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp it should be this peace 'else { next_coin_value = next_coin(coin_value); calculate_change(remainder,next_coin_value); }' , but it is not really working.

Comment: There should be no `else`. The part about printing the value has nothing to do with the rest of the function.

Comment: Solved it by substituting coin_value for another variable and puting the remainder declaration out of the while statement. All done.

Comment: `int value;
 value = 100; 
 
    calculate_change(change_needed,value);`